# Proper Ternary Operator Format

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

This is what I have. I'm unsure how to properly write it. I tried Googling around, but to no avail. Please don't cringe too much:

```
cout << (guess > randomNumber) ? "\nWhoops! Try again!\n You guessed higher than the random number!\n\n"
        : (guess < randomNumber) ? "\nWhoops! Try again!\n You guessed lower than the random number!\n\n"
        : "";
```

What I'm wanting it to do is this:

```
    // Gives hint that inputted number is higher or lower
    // than inputted number
    if (guess > randomNumber)
        cout << "\nWhoops! Try again!"
        << " You guessed higher than the random number!\n"
        << endl;
    else if (guess < randomNumber)
        cout << "\nWhoops! Try again!"
        << " You guessed lower than the random number!\n"
        << endl;
```

Any help would be appreciated. I just want to learn how I can write my programs to be more efficient and smaller. Would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Using one ternary operator is efficient... Using two at the same time is messier if you ask me.

Comment: The code looks ok to me. Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use nested ternary operator instead of that `if`/`else if`? It's way much easier to tell what your program is doing by looking at it instead of decrypting those nested ternary operators.

Comment: I've tried running it, and all it does it output a 0 with no spaces. It compiles correctly, but doesn't print either options.

Also, this is my first time posting on this site, so forgive me if I'm doing this wrong. :)

Comment: Note that I have deleted a reply of mine cthat was intended to help.   It was marked down within less than 20 seconds of my posting it.   And it was long enough that it could not have even been read in that time.   Clearly, some other respondents are marking down replies to highlight their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put some brackets around the entire expression, otherwise you're going to end up printing boolean values:

```
int guess = 10;
    int randomNumber = 9;

    cout << (guess > randomNumber) ? "\nWhoops! Try again!\n You guessed higher than the random number!\n\n"
            : (guess < randomNumber) ? "\nWhoops! Try again!\n You guessed lower than the random number!\n\n"
            : "" ;

// Output: 1
```

Proper code:

```
int guess = 10;
    int randomNumber = 9;

    cout << ( (guess > randomNumber) ? "\nWhoops! Try again!\n You guessed higher than the random number!\n\n"
            : (guess < randomNumber) ? "\nWhoops! Try again!\n You guessed lower than the random number!\n\n"
            : "" ); // Notice the brackets!

/*Output:
Whoops! Try again!
You guessed higher than the random number!*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you for getting it to work. :)

Comment: @red-one Please mark it as solved if that is the case! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> more efficient

Not related to what you're doing there (if by "efficient" you mean better runtime characteristics).

> smaller

A humble goal, but **not** if *readability* falls short because of it (and even less so if, because of the syntactic complexity ... missing parentheses ... the end result is wrong).

*Remember: Code is written for humans to read.*

You should probably stick with the `if` and `else` approach you're also showing in the question. That said, an IMHO "good" approach (if you really need to abstract over this) would be to pack it into some function:

```
template<class T, class X, class Y, class Z>
void comp_if(T value, T reference, X less, Y equal, Z greater) {
  if (value < reference) less();
  else if (value > reference) greater();
  else equal();
}
```

Used like

```
// missing real macros a lot
comp_if(foo, bar,
  []() {cout << "less"; },
  []() {cout << "equal";},
  []() {cout << "greater"});
```

Whether this really helps with readability is a choice I leave up to the reader to make.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I haven't learned that much in C++ yet. I'm still a beginner, so.. But I do understand your point about readability. Specifically for this, I wanted to just condense. But I will take your advice into account in future programs. :)

Comment: @RedOne No problem. The approach taken in my answer will really only be beneficial if you have *a lot* of such code. Always try to achieve as readable as possible code. You'll make a lot less errors when doing so, because it will be easier to keep every thing in mind. (Log n mental depth vs n mental width)

Comment: @anonymous downvoters: please explain the reasons for your vote.  My post IMHO answers the question in a pretty direct way. I don't think my answer deserves such votes just because I didn't highlight the small syntax error (but instead provided better approaches).

Comment: @DanielJour I feel like your answer hits a weird spot where you aim to improve readability (which can easily be done with some if/else statements like OP noted) and instead hit upon template functions and lambdas, which I think is out of OP's scope, judging from the question. Perhaps my opinion is too harsh, I would change my vote but it's locked until the answer is changed.

Comment: @058094041 My approach is able to improve readability *a lot* in the (very very) niche case of having *really a lot* such 3 way decisions in the code *but* no clear "interface" to the problem they're trying to solve. This also really only makes any sense when the executed code paths (the lambdas) become more complex (in what they do, not how they look). I know that I definitely got out of the scope of OP here, and I edited my answer to highlight something that couldn't be easily understood before: The if else approach is better for almost all cases.

Comment: @DanielJour +1. fair point. As long as OP understands what's happening here I see no problem.